# can't get the value of an HTML dropdown with Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I try to make a dropdown select with Ionic (angular) but it's doesn't work for me
please what I'm missing

I want to get the value of the element selected by the user but when I want to show in the `console.log` nothing Showed

I know it's simple but it won't work for me

HTML code

```html
<ion-select
      value="السنة"
      okText="Okay"
      cancelText="Dismiss"
      (change)="selectYear($event)"
    >
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of year" value="{{item.value}}"
        >{{item.value}}</ion-select-option
      >
    </ion-select>
```

here the ts file :

```js
year= [{value:2019},{value:2020},{value:2021}];
yearSelected:number;

 selectYear(e:any) {
    this.yearSelected = e.target.value;
    console.log(this.yearSelected)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the event `(ionChange)` instead of `(change)`:

```html
<ion-select
    value="السنة"
    okText="Okay"
    cancelText="Dismiss"
    (ionChange)="selectYear($event)"
>
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of year" value="{{item.value}}"> 
        {{item.value}}
    </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Also, the value received is just the plain value, not an event:

```js
selectYear(value: any) {
    this.yearSelected = value;
    console.log(this.yearSelected)
}
```

Comment: thank you, friend, I miss this .... thank you so much for helping me that mean a lot to me